# Using same gateway on all workstations, but two workstations have no outside access

Tags: networking, internet, dns, gateway, windows-networking

I have 11 computers, all of which should be using the same gateway to reach out to the internet and also to resolve for primary DNS.

9 of the 11 machines have no issue, but two of the machines will not take the default gateway to reach out to the web, but are able to use the gateway IP to resolve DNS. All of said stations are attached to the same devices.

Any suggestions? I've run out of ideas.

Added images of the routing tables. I checked routes previously, but didn't pick anything up. Unless, now that I'm looking at it...I believe I need to lower the metric value of the gateway I'm using.
This first image is the machine with the gateway working

<sup>there is currently a 192.168.24.1 gateway on the non-working machine, this is because these stations are on a site where they need to be online as much as possible. there was an old gateway device in place, but a new device was installed to take its place</sup>
[image: Machine with no issue]

This one is not
[image: Not working]

Comment: 1) Are their any differences in the routing tables of the devices which do not work compared to the devices which do work?  If so can you add the output of `route print`.  2) Can those 2 devices reach the the gateway for DNS via IPv4? (Or are they the only two supporting IP v6 and using that for DNS?).

Comment: Added. Now that I'm taking a second look, I believe I need to lower the metric value.

Comment: On the working machine the gateway is set to 192.168.24.252, on the host where it does not work you have a persistent route setting it it 192.169.24.1. This does not match with "*all of which should be using the same gateway*".

Comment: Right, it's the working configuration at the moment. These machines are on a site where they need to be online. They were using a different gateway previously, but I installed a new device to take it's place.

Comment: Edited again :)

Comment: No one has any ideas?

Comment: Question is not helpful to a wider audience

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The device that was purchased by the purchasing agents at the company that I work for has a 10 user license limit. We simply need to purchase an upgraded license.

I dug through  the firewall logs and found that it was denying traffic from two of our work stations with the message "10 user license limit exceeded"

I love when things are this simple.

Comment: Does that mean that your post is closed?

Comment: Yea everything is fine, post can be closed

Answer (score 1):

You have a old persistent route from when the computer was on site, just do the following command and maybe reboot and it should delete the old gateway that was replaced.

```
route delete 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: I will give that a try. Even when entering a new gateway, a persistent route will supersede the gateway I enter?

Comment: Yes, I believe it does override them.

Comment: Just wanted to double check on the other machine (because 2 of them are having this problem), the other one does not have a persistent route, but it is in the tables. I will try this and report back

Comment: That didn't fix it